# Bounded sequence and limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose we have a bounded sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$. Let

$$x_n = \frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot a_k = \frac{2}{n(n+1)}(a_1+2a_2+\cdots+na_n)$$

for $n \in \mathbb N$.

I am trying to figure out whether these statements are true.

$$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n \leq \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$$

$$\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n \geq \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$$

I think the above equation can be expressed as

$$\frac{2}{n(n+1)}(a_1+2a_2+\cdots+na_n) = \frac{a_1+2a_2+\cdots+na_n}{1+2+\cdots+n}$$

but I am not sure if this has anything to do with limsup and liminf.

Am I approaching this problem correctly?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: See [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#The_general_form) (the general form).